# TinyMCE self-hosted, font cannot load - access denied (403)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, tinymce

I am setting up a TinyMCE self-hosted instance on an AWS S3 bucket. The editor may only be loaded from a specific domain, so I am trying to setup the bucket policy for this. But I cannot get it to work properly.

My S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "<some-id>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<some-id>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://127.0.0.1:3000/*",
                        "https://127.0.0.1:3000/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My CORS settings on the bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

With these settings I can load the TinyMCE editor from the bucket on `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`, but the editor cannot load the `tinymce.woff` & `tinymce.ttf`. Doing this gives a `net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)`. So I think the origin of the request of the fonts is not 'http(s)://127.0.0.1:3000/'.

---

The request headers TinyMCE adds to fetch the fonts is:

```
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Referer: https://<bucket-location>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

The configuration of TinyMCE in my application is:

```
export const editor = {
    elementpath: false, // Disable html display in bottom bar ('p >> span' for example)
    branding: false, // Disable 'powered by TinyMCE' text
    height: '100%',
    resize: false, // Disable editor resize
    protocol: 'https', // Load assets via HTTPS | <--- Changing this does not work
}
```

---

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

The `Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000` header that is present on the font requests is **NOT** present on the fetch editor request. This is why I think the request doesn't originates from `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

The editor without fonts looks as follows, so the fonts are needed:
[image: editor without font]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the TinyMCE instance on the S3 bucket was loading it's resources that were on the same S3 bucket, but I only gave access from other domains to the bucket (via the bucket policy).

Due to this the request TinyMCE made to fetch it's fonts was denied. This can be easily resolved by adding the bucket url to the allowed origins, so that the bucket can make requests to itself.

My updated bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "<some-id>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<some-id>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://<bucket-location>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/*", // <-- This is new
                        "http://127.0.0.1:3000/*",
                        "https://127.0.0.1:3000/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```